# Why line current is increasing when electrical devices are powered on using circuit breakers instead of normal switch?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, current, dc, circuit-breaker

[image]

My connection was very simple. Just a PLC with no load. It draws very little current. Usually, while working, I keep on the Over Current Protection mode. No problem happens if I turn on or off the PLC using the power supply switch and select the output current of 1 amp or less.

But if I use the circuit breaker to turn on the system, the over-current protection is triggered. The over-current protection is triggered even when the power supply current is selected 5 amp. I also got a high current spike in the oscilloscope during turning on with circuit breaker.

The circuit breaker is type C and is rated 4 amp. Can anyone explain what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely explanation is the PLC has a large capacitor on its 24VDC power supply, which would be reasonable if it is expected to operate on dirty "industrial" 24V.

When you use the power supply's on/off switch, it will gently ramp up the voltage and charge the capacitors in the device without causing a large current spike. However when you use the circuit breaker as a switch, the discharged capacitor is connected to the power supply directly, so it draws a high current to charge.

The breaker does not trip because it is a "C" curve which is designed to allow inrush current spikes like motor starting current or from SMPS capacitors. It is designed to protect against fire while avoiding nuisance tripping. A 4A breaker would need quite a lot of time to trip on a 5A current, perhaps tens of seconds. It would trip quickly on a short circuit, but that causes a much higher current than the power supply's 5A limit. You can find the time it takes to trip versus current in the breaker's datasheet.

The power supply's current limiter is designed to avoid destroying fragile electronic components, so it is much faster and more accurate, and it will trip in this case. This is normal and it's a good thing, because if it did not, this linear power supply's output transistor would suffer from this large current spike.

Basically both components are doing the job they were designed to do.

Comment: Note that if you dig deeply enough you can find time vs. trip charts for most current-production circuit breakers.  Same deal for fuses.